# Cone problem - function of height vs time

Tags: functions

in one of my courses I need to write a problem and I thought about one I just don't know how can I apply it so I will thank to anyone who can help.
In this problem you have a cone with the capacity of 100 milliliter. and a height of 15 cm. A man pours liquid in a constant rate of 5 milliliter per second (in 20 seconds the class will be full) find the height of the liquid as a function of time.

now, I'm sure it's not perfect, and I think there's missing data to find the function but I'm not sure what. Right now all I need to solve it is to find a cone radios witch is a part of a big cone that I know it's data. and a has a volume of 5t (the smaller cone).

Comment: I do not think there is any missing data to find the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to write a formula for the volume inside your cone with respect to height. You can start with the formula for the volume of a cone:

$$
V=\frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}
$$
But note here that the radius of your base is actually a linear function of $h$, and so you can write $r=ch$ for some constant $c$, and then we have
$$
V=\frac{\pi c^2h^3}{3}
$$
Now, you can solve for $c$ using the parameters you know (total volume and height of the cone).

You also know that the volume of liquid in the cone is $5t$, so you replace $V$ with $5t$, and rearrange to solve for $h$ in the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I just solved it and it's great, I have only one question how do you know that h vs r is linear? is this because the shape of side of the cone? a diagonal?

Comment: You're welcome :) that's right, you know this because of the shape of the cone; If you look at a vertical cross section of your cone, it will look like a triangle, and we know that the hypotenuse (also the side of your cone) is a straight line